# I use =GOOGLEFINANCE in my google sheet. Does it update hourly even when the sheet is closed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

here is my spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jU8n0xVcN8M1h9a6rOaN8Cjax7J6znJc2ZXgoioY8oc/edit?usp=sharing

I use it to track my portfolio. I have a script enabled that scours the internet for the current market values of my investment funds (since some are not available as tickers on GOOGLE FINANCE). However, some are available on GOOGLE FINANCE (e.g. VOO and VXUS). The ones I scripted update once daily, then I have a another script to log each daily value on a history log so I can see how it changes over time.

My question is, when the sheet is closed, i.e. not open by me on any device, does the google finance formula (i.e. `=iferror(GoogleFinance(B6,"price"),"No Data")`) update hourly as well?

I have already gone to File>Settings>Calculations>Enabled Calculation Refreshes every hour.

My question is simply if this hourly-updating only works when the sheet is open, or does it work when the sheet is closed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have not used it in several  years, but in my experience you cannot depend upon the hourly update rate.   I've seen situations were it can miss several triggers in a row.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no official documentation for that, as GOOGLEFINANCE can't be retrieved programmatically due to Google restrictions, it doesn't make sense that these formulas be recalculated when nobody has the spreadsheet open.